# why Interrupted exception thrown here...reason?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

```
public class TwoThreads {
    private static Object resource = new Object();

    private static void delay(long n) {
        try 
        { 
            Thread.sleep(n);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("StartMain ");
        new Thread1().start();
        delay(1000);                       //dealay 1
        Thread t2 = new Thread2();
        t2.start();   
        delay(1000);                      // delay 2    
        t2.interrupt();                   //here its throwing exception
        delay(1000);                      //delay 3
        System.out.print("EndMain ");
    }

    static class Thread1 extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (resource) {
                System.out.print("Startl ");
                delay(6000);
                System.out.print("End1 ");
            }
        }
    }

    static class Thread2 extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (resource) {
                System.out.print("Start2 ");
                delay(2000);
                System.out.print("End2 ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just got confused here why `t2.interrupt()` is not throwing exception when t2 is waiting to acquire lock on resource object and `interrupt()` method might throw security exception then why compiler still allowing us to execute it without putting it into try catch block.

Comment: Your question is unclear: the comment in your code says an exception is thrown but your text below the code says no exception is thrown. And the part on security exception is not very clear either...

Comment: yes it is throwing interrupted exception and about security exception it was another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synchronized block doesn't throw an InterruptedException and interrupting a thread blocking while attempting to acquire a monitor this way doesn't do anything.

If you want this functionality you need to use a Lock which has [lockInterruptibly()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lockInterruptibly%28%29), though this is not often used.

> Acquires the lock unless the current thread is interrupted. Acquires
>   the lock if it is not held by another thread and returns immediately,
>   setting the lock hold count to one.
>
> If the current thread already holds this lock then the hold count is
>   incremented by one and the method returns immediately.
>
> If the lock is held by another thread then the current thread becomes
>   disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of
>   two things happens:
>
> The lock is acquired by the current thread; or Some other thread
>   interrupts the current thread. If the lock is acquired by the current
>   thread then the lock hold count is set to one.
>
> If the current thread: 
>   has its interrupted status set on entry to this method; or is
>   interrupted while acquiring the lock, then InterruptedException is
>   thrown and the current thread's interrupted status is cleared.

Comment: also security exception is a runtime exception therefore compiler is not complaining

Answer (score 1):

From [Thread#interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29):

> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt status will be set.

If you checked `t2.interrupted()`, you'd see a `true` result, but the thread is blocking on entering the `synchronized` block, which doesn't trigger an `InterruptedException`.

A call to `interrupt()` may throw a `SecurityException` if the application's environment has set up restrictions on which threads can interact with others, but this doesn't apply in your simple example.

Comment: ok, as it doesn't trigger an InterruptedException at that time then the main thread sleeps beacuse of delay 3 and then it prints endMain then after that what triggers interrupted exception to be thrown

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear but I guess I understood it correct so I am attempting to answer.

`syncrhonized` blocks are **NOT** responsive to interrupts.

For that you can use explicit locks `Lock`, which has a method `lockInterruptibly()` which is responsive to interrupts.

[lockInterruptibly() in Lock Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lockInterruptibly%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.Thread.interrupt()** means Interrupts this thread.

Unless the current thread is interrupting itself, which is always permitted, the **checkAccess** method of this thread is invoked, which may cause a **SecurityException** to be thrown.

**If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class**, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an **InterruptedException**.

you have called sleep() on t2. that is the reason of getting interruptedException.